# How to check either I have a new database entry and show in notification bar with alert

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-views

I am getting data in django of a ajax from database like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/activity/',
    type: 'GET',
    data:{},
    success: function(data) {
        // alert(data);
        var div1 = document.getElementById('activity');
        div=data;      
        div1.appendChild(div);
       });
```

And this ajax is set to be on a run on page refresh , but now I want to check if user have new message and on page. So without refresh want to show message .
How can I achieve this thing. d

Comment: When do you want to do this?

Comment: @Taplar  when a message in database for user

Comment: @Taplar  like for user_id  1  I have 1 new msg It should show  alert , and when 2nd message it should show 2 .

Comment: The page has no clue that the database has a new message.  You have to check for it.  To do that you have to initiate a request to check.  I'm asking when, or by what event, do you want to initiate that request?

Comment: @Taplar  I have a message system , I am saving that msg in database with his id , now wanted to show in notification bar when User is on page  without refreshing  page for every msg . you got my point ?

Comment: I understand what you're asking.  But you seem to be under the assumption that your browser is in constant communication with your server and your server will just tell it an update has happened.  That's not how http requests work.  To do what you are asking, you have to either write logic that uses timed polling, long polling, or uses websockets to implement a true push process for your server to tell your browser an update has happened.  All of those possibilities are too broad for a single question.

Comment: @Taplar  oh I am new on this topic. I think websockets or long push would be good. but what you suggest in this scenario ?

Comment: @Taplar  and I am using pusher for chatting . but there is no notify system I think so thats why I am finding solution

Comment: @Taplar  I want same like stackoverflow notifications .

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

- have the server push the record to the browser using a websocket
- have the browser pull the record by doing long-polling.

Comment: you beat me too it!

Comment: thanks for reply . any particle example of both these ?